Найти все числа у которых три делителя в диапазоне от 2 до 50
Не могу найти все числа у которых три делителя в диапазоне от 2 до 50. Что делаю не так?
Пробовала двумя разными вариантами. Когда делаю первым способом, vscode находит только два делителя 1 и 50, вторым способом вообще ничего не работает.
def f(n):
    lst = []
    for i in range(1, int(n**0.5)):
        if n % i == 0:
            lst.append(i)
            lst.append(n // 1)
            return lst
        
print(f(50))

for i in range(2, 50+1):
    a = []
    for j in range(2, i):
        if i % j == 0:
            a.append(j)
if len(a) == 3:
    print(a)


Вы, наверное, хотели написать lst.append(n // i ), но это на суть не влияет. В первом коде можно добиться успеха, если список не создавать, а просто считать множители, но обязательно  учитывая случай i*i==n - а он для вас как раз и важен. Второй трудно читать, поправьте

что значит "vscode находит"? это как вообще?

Признаюсь честно, я осваиваю пайтон за один день, очень нужно)) С синтаксисом проблемы, я поправила отступы, стало получше, выводит мне массив [1, 50, 2, 50, 5, 50]. Но мне нужны не сами делители, а числа, у которых три делителя в указанном диапазоне

Даже и не знаю, я вижу, что вы очень умный и с питоном и с математикой, наверное, все ок, не подскажете решение?)

Поправочка, не менее трех делителей нужно, больше можно, меньше нет

Ну вот, очень жаль

Ну вы сами логику продумайте, это основа программирования. В цикле перебираете числа. Для цикла for i in range на каждом шаге проверяете число i. Для этого числа посчитали множители. Если вы их решили в список заносить - ну и ладно, проверили длину списка и в случае успеха выводите что? Само число i, а не список. И отступ последнего if неверный, он должен быть внутри цикла
